# A criterion for the sum of two closed sets to be closed ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, convexity

Let  $V$ and $I$ be two closed subsets of a Banach space $A$.

The set $V$ is a convex cone, and $I$ is a linear subspace of $A$. I also know that $V\cap I=\{0\}$.

I would like to know whether $I+V$ is closed. I've seen that there is a criterion of Dieudonné which I can't use here because I know that neither $V$ nor $I$ is locally compact.

So my question is : are there any other criteria that I could try to use ?

Comment: Maybe I should add that by "criterion" I mean a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When $V$ is also a subspace, the standard equivalence to the sum being closed is that the unit spheres of $V$ and $I$ are a positive distance apart.  I bet this is true when $V$ is just a convex cone but don't have time right now to think about it (the given condition is clearly sufficient for closedness of the sum; necessity is the direction that requires thought).

EDIT: It will come to no surprise to those who know me that I lose my bet. Let $A$ be $\ell_p$, $1\le p < \infty$ ($c_0$ is also OK with suitable notational changes)  and $x^*$ the linear functional $\sum 2^{-n} e_n$, where $e_n$ is the unit vector basis for $A^* = \ell_q$, $1/p + 1/q = 1$.  $I$ is the kernel of $x^*$ and $V$ are the non negative vectors in $A$. In Pietro's notation, $\pi(V)$ is closed because it is a cone which contains its base point in a one dimensional space and hence, as Pietro remarked, $V+I$ is closed in $A$.  For $n>1$ let $x_n=e_n-2^{-n+1}e_1 \in I$ and observe that $e_n-x_n\to 0$.

Comment: Ok, I managed to show that if the unit spheres of the subspaces $V-V$ and $I$ are a positive distance apart then $V+I$ is closed under the hypotheses I have given. The subspace $V-V$ need not be closed, only $V$ has to be. The sufficient condition was all I cared for, and this one works in the case I have at hand. So I thank you and accept your answer.
 

Answer (score 7):

In general, there is no easy criterion. I recall the construction of two closed subspaces
of a Banach space whose sum is not closed: Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear map between Banach spaces with closed graph $G= \{ (x,T(x)): x\in X \}$. Then $L=\{(\xi,0): \xi\in X\}$
is another closed (even complemented) subspace such that $G+L= X\times T(X)$ which is
closed if and only if $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$. Moreover, $G\cap L=0$ if $T$ is injective.
A concrete example is obtained for the inclusion $\ell_1 \hookrightarrow \ell_2$ (in this case the sum is dense).

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to mention the following, even though it is just a reformulation: For $V\subset X $ and $I\subset X$ a closed linear subspace, the sum  $V+I$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $\pi(V)$ is closed in the quotient $X/I\\ $, $\pi:X\to X/I$ being the quotient map.

(Reason: Indeed, if  $\pi(V)$ is closed, so is $V+I=\pi^{-1}\pi(V)$. On the other hand, if $V+I$ is closed and $\xi\in \overline{ \pi(V) }$, then $\xi$ is limit of a sequence $\xi_n\in \pi(V) $ with $\| \xi_n - \xi_{n+1}\|_{X/I}\le 2^{-n}$ and by definition of the quotient norm there exists an inductively defined sequence $w_n\in V+I$  such that $\xi_n=\pi w_n$ and $\|w_n -w_{n+1}\| _ X < 2^{-n}$; therefore $(w_n)_n $ is a Cauchy sequence in  the closed set $V + I$ and converges to an element $w\in V + I$ such that $\pi w=\xi$, which proves that $\pi(V)$ is closed in $X/I$).

Answer (score 3):

In finite dimensional space, your result is true. Take a linear functional with $\text{ker } T = I$. It is not hard to prove, using $I\cap V={\boldsymbol 0}$, that $T(V)$ is closed by seeing that $$\text{inf }_{\begin{array}{c}\boldsymbol x \in V \\  \|\boldsymbol x\| = 1\end{array}} \|T(\boldsymbol x)\| > 0,$$ with the minimum achieved. Thus, by Lemma H1 of the book Geometric Functional Analysis and its Applications, $I+V$ is closed.

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused. Doesn't [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/423284/102946) to [your question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423174/102946) imply that $V+I$ is closed for all vector subspaces $I$ only if the cone $V$ is polyhedral?

Comment: @JochenGlueck indeed, take the cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose intersection with the plane $z=c$, for $c \geq 0$, is the closed disc of radius $c$ centered at $(c,0,c)$. Its projection onto the $xy$-plane is the open half-space $x > 0$ plus the origin.

Comment: In infinite dimensional space, the criterion may fail. Basically because balls are not compact sets.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was afraid that I was overlooking something - apparently I didn't see the assumption $I \cap V= \{0\}$. Thanks for the clarification, @R.W.Prado! By the would, could you make the reference a bit more precise? I only found one book with this title (by Holmes, 1975), but the theorems and lemmas there are not enumerated, and there are various subsections enumerated as "H".

Comment: Hmm, I browsed through the book for a while and could now find the closedness statement itself (of $I+V$, when $I \cap V = \{0\}$ and $I$ is finite dimensional) in the corollary on page 105. Very nice book!

Comment: I edited my answer to enlight the hypotesis he has that is needed to prove his statement. But the OP added such hypotesis in his question

Comment: @R.W.Prado Thanks for this proof ! This also follows from Dieudonné's criterion (proposition 1 of Math. Ann. 163 (1966), available here https://eudml.org/doc/161348). In the case at hand, this criterion boils down to the local compactness of either V or I.

Answer (score 2):

Please, have a look at Sections 22 and 35 in G.J.O. Jameson, "Topology and Normed Spaces", Chapman and Hall, 1974.

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you included the relevant statements found therein.

Comment: While I agree with @AlexM., I would like to add that, anyway, this reference is really great! (I just looked it up, and it contains a lot of interesting stuff, in particular if one is interested in ordered Banach spaces).