# Are the polyhedral cones the only examples of cones that remains closed when they are added to vector subspaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, polyhedra

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed convex cone. If one wants to know whether the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to\mathbb{R}^m$ sends the closed set $C$ to another closed one, $T(C)$, it is needed to prove that $\text{ker } T + C$ is closed.

My concern turns into to know whether there exist good examples of cones, other than polyhedral cones, that are mapped to closed sets by any linear map. Hence, the question is reduced to:

> There exist a closed convex cone $C$, different from any polyhedral cone,  such that, for every vector subspace $V$, $V+C$ is closed?

The article [On the closedness of the linear image of a closed convex cone](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/epdf/10.1287/moor.1060.0242) almost answers my question. If one can find an enlightening example of cone $C$ satisfying the condition (SUM-WE) for every subspace, my example is constructed.

Comment: Since the linked article is behind a paywall it might be useful to formulate explicitely the *SUM-WE* condition.

Comment: A copy of this article is available at the homepage of the author: http://gaborpataki.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/14119/2018/07/closed1published.pdf

Comment: The fact that a closed convex cone is polyhedral iff all its projections are closed (which is essentially your question) was proved in 1957 in H.Mirkil, "New characterizations of polyhedral cones". See also the 1959 paper by V.Klee, "Some characterizations of convex polyhedra".

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun,  there is a question  by a student who heard one of your talks, something about a  cone in $\mathbb R^3$  with a dense set of planar cross sections.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469943/is-there-a-closed-convex-subset-c-of-mathbbr3-such-that-any-closed-co   Is there a standard reference  for this sort of thing?

Comment: I don't know of reference but had wrote up a note about this 
http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/aubrun/recherche/dense-projective-orbit.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The radial cone of $C$ is defined via
$$
\mathcal R_C(x) := \bigcup_{\lambda > 0} \lambda ( C - x)$$
for all $x \in C$
and we can show
$$
\mathcal R_C(x) = C + \operatorname{span}(x),
$$
since $C$ is a cone.
By assumption $\mathcal R_C(x)$ is closed for all $x \in C$, since $\operatorname{span}(x)$ is a subspace. But now,
Proposition 2 of [Duality of linear conic problems by Shapiro and Nemirovski](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2003/12/793.pdf)
implies that $C$ is a polyhedral cone.

Comment: Holly mother of god! In the foundations of my  pure being, and in my full essence, this is a completely  unexpected result. God! That was unexpected! I was trully not hoping to find a "new" characterization of polyedral cones.